# Mono for Android preprocessor macros

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, c-preprocessor

Is there an Android preprocessor macros that Mono for Android defines?

I mean very useful things for cross-platform development like:

```
#if WINDOWS...#endif
```

and

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE...#endif
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
__ANDROID__
```

and additionally for each Android API Level:

```
__ANDROID_4__;__ANDROID_7__;__ANDROID_8__;etc
```