# Mono for Android preprocessor macro not working

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, c-preprocessor

In reference to this question: [Mono for Android preprocessor macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917859/mono-for-android-preprocessor-macros)

I am trying to do some cross-platform work and need to get the `__ANDROID__` macro to work. However in visual studio it is not picking it up. Am I doing something wrong? The project is a Mono for Android project and I have just updated to the latest version.

Example code (it keeps on going into the #else):

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
                if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(CellNumberKey))
                {
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[CellNumberKey] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add(CellNumberKey, value);
                }

                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
#elif __ANDROID__

#else
                NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString (value, CellNumberKey);
                NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize ();
#endif
```

Comment: Does it pass if you define `__ANDROID__` as a custom symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested and it's working for me in VS2010 in both a library and an executable project - working within Mono for Android 4.2.2

However, the syntax highlighting was "a little screwy" - in particular it only picked up that the `__ANDROID__` code was live after I had done a build on the affected project.

Comment: It did seem to 'wake up' after rebuilding. Strange, Resharper was moaning and intellisense was going crazy.

Comment: The difference here is that the Android symbols are defined as part of the build process, rather than being defined as part of the project's build configurations like WINDOWS_PHONE. VS/Resharper likely have no way of knowing about it until it gets built.